# Kubernetes|Helm values.yaml - How to access array using dynamic index

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a `values.yaml` where I need to mention multiple ports like the following:

```
kafkaClientPort:
  - 32000
  - 32001
  - 32002
```

In yaml for statefulset, I need to get value using ordinal number.
So for `kf-0`, I need to put first element of `kafkaClientPort`; and for `kf-1`, second element and so on.
I am trying like the following:

```
args:
- "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://$(MY_NODE_NAME):{{ index .Values.kafkaClientPort ${HOSTNAME##*-} }}"
```

But it is showing an error.

Please advise what is the best way to access dynamically `values.yaml` value.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is that Helm template doesn't know anything about ordinal in your stateful set.  If you look at the Kafka [Helm Chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/e0874c51fa95c1f9fafc1f8fdd714891642caa51/incubator/kafka/values.yaml#L176), you see that they are using a base port `31090` and then they add the ordinal number but that substitution is in place 'after' the template is created. Something like this in your values:

```
"advertised.listener": |-
   PLAINTEXT://kafka.cluster.local:$((31090 + ${KAFKA_BROKER_ID}))
```

and then in the template file, the [use a bash export under `command`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/3cacbb20dfc067bb601393aca87c17df80cf4ee6/incubator/kafka/templates/statefulset.yaml#L203) with a `printf` which is an alias for `fmt.Sprintf`. Something like this in your case:

```
    command:
    - sh
    - -exc
    - |
      unset KAFKA_PORT && \
      export KAFKA_BROKER_ID=${HOSTNAME##*-} && \
      export "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS={{ printf "%s" $advertised.listener }} \\
      ...
```